# Non-algebraic structures?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, transcendental-numbers

We call group, ring, field,... "algebraic structures". Do we have similar analogue for transcendental numbers? If not, then how do we study interactions between various transcendental numbers?

Also, both irrational numbers and transcendental numbers are uncountable, is it a reason for their inability to form algebraic structures?

Comment: The reals are uncountable and still form an algebraic structure, a field.

Comment: You can e.g. define a group structure on any set, so it is not true, that transcendental or irrational numbers do *not* form an algebraic structure.

Comment: @flawr can you please give an explicit example of such group,  it will be really helpful.

Comment: @menag thanks, one myth busted!

Comment: @rationalbeing Take the irrational numbers. As they have the same cardinality is the real numbers, you can take a bijection $\phi$ that maps an irrational number to a real number. Then we make use of the additive group structure on the real numbers and define our new operation $+_t$ as $a +_t b := \phi^{-1}( \phi(a) + \phi(b))$. This operation defines a group structure on the irrational numbers.

Comment: @flawr this is nice existence proof. Can't we have something straightforward as in case of rational numbers?

Comment: What would you consider *straightforward*? It is not only an existence proof. It is quite easy to explicitly construct a bijection like that, you can find quite a few examples here on math.SE.

Comment: @flawr thanks :)

Comment: If we just take the group generated by the irrationals as a subset of $\Bbb R$ (meaning the operation is the usual $+$), we get the entirety of $\Bbb R$. For example, $1$ would be in it, because $1=(1-\pi)+(\pi)$ and $1-\pi$ and $\pi$ are both irrational.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question doesn't really make sense.  The term "algebraic numbers" is only very loosely related to the term "algebraic structure": both have to do with algebraic operations, but there is no reason at all that an algebraic structure needs to consist of algebraic numbers (or numbers of any kind, for that matter).

In particular, there is nothing from stopping you from using the usual structures of abstract algebra to study relationships between different transcendental numbers.  For instance, $\mathbb{C}$ is a field which contains all of the transcendental numbers.  So you can study algebraic relationships between different transcendental numbers inside the field $\mathbb{C}$.

What is true is that (for instance) the set of all transcendental numbers does not form a field under the usual operations, since it is not closed under those operations (for instance, $\pi$ and $-\pi$ are transcendental, but their sum $0$ is not).  However, you can still study them perfectly well by considering them as a subset of a larger algebraic structure.

Answer (score 1):

In group theory there is the [Frattini subgroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frattini_subgroup) of a group $G$, which consists of all the elements of $G$ which do not belong to any minimal generating set. It is in some sense the collection of all the "least nice" elements of the group, yet it happens to be a (sub)group itself.

More generally, there is the universal algebra concept of a **Frattini subalgebra** of an algebra $\mathbf{A}$, which is the subalgebra generated by all elements of $A$ which do not belong to any minimal generating set for $\mathbf{A}$. You might find it instructive to try to determine, for example, the Frattini subgroup of the reals under addition, since this is both "bad" in the sense you seem to be asking for and also has "natural" structure.